# Is there any environment variable showing rebuild information in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Rebuilder plugin version 1.31 in my Jenkins system. I find that when I rebuild a pipeline task, under "console output" tag I can see something like **"Rebuilds build #12"**, so is there any environment variable that I can use in the pipeline script like `currentBuild.rebuild` telling me that it is triggered by "rebuild #12"? Now that Jenkins knows it is a rebuild task, I think there should be a variable showing the rebuild information.

Comment: See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#get-build-cause or search here for "build cause". One of the possible Build Causes is "rebuild".

Comment: Thanks to @MaratC. In the return value of `currentBuild.getBuildCauses()` I can see information related to rebuilding.